# Comparar dos listas anidadas por un subindice y devolver el indice donde está la diferencia

Tags: python

Tengo dos listas anidadas en python como sigue:

```
lista1 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
lista2 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','10']]
```

Deseo compararlas tomando en cuenta el tercer subíndice de cada una, por ejemplo: para la lista 1: 3, 6 y 9 con 3, 6 y 10 de la lista2.

Necesito que me devuelva como respuesta el índice donde se encuentra la diferencia, en este caso el tercero de la lista2: `[7,8,10]`
No sé como iterar las listas para compararlas y obtener el resultado propuesto, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
dif =[]
for i in lista1:
    for j in lista2:
        if lista1[i][2] != lista2[j][2]:
            dif.append(lista2[j])
print(dif)
```

peo obtengo una excepción en el `if`.

Comment: Hola Ariel, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Has intentado algo para resolverlo? De ser así deberías agregarlo, que el código no funcione o el enfoque sea incorrecto es irrelevante. Puedes hacerlo eficientemente en un solo `for` realmente, mirate [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) y [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Por cierto, ¿solo existe una diferencia (o ninguna) siempre?¿O podría haber más de un índice que difieran?

Comment: el codigo que intenté despues de mucho esfuerzo es el siguiente pero no me da un buen resultado, disulpe la ignorancia de zip y enumerate, voy a revisar:                                                                                                                                    dif =[]

for i in lista1:
    for j in lista2:
        if lista1[i][2] != lista2[j][2]:
            dif.append(lista2[j])
print(dif)

Comment: Usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/324219/edit) que hay debajo de la pregunta y agrega el código que quieras en ella, luego lo seleccionas y pulsas `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor para que se formatee correctamente. Los comentarios son mal sitio para agregar código, no respetan la identacion y eso en Python es un problema XD, aparte están limitados en cuanto a tamaño.

Comment: Procura siempre añadir el detalle de la excepción que te arroja al usar tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que obtienes es bastante aclaratorio del problema:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
>     if lista1[i][2] != lista2[j][2]:
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
> ```

es decir, te está diciendo que `i` en `lista1[i][2]` es una lista y no un entero, por lo que no es un índice válido.

En Python, cuando recorres una lista (u otro iterable) con un `for in`, lo que obtienes y almacenas en la variable del `for` (`i` en este caso) es cada item del mismo, no sus índices. Puedes verlo de forma simple imprimiendo `i`:

```
dif =[]
for i in lista1:
    print(i)
```

> ```
> ['1', '2', '3']
> ['4', '5', '6']
> ['7', '8', '9']
> ```

Dado que debes recorrer ambas listas a la par, no debes usar un `for` anidado, basta con un solo ciclo. Si quieres usar indizado, usa un `for` junto a `range` para generar los índices:

```
dif =[]
for i in range(len(lista1)):
    if lista1[i][2] != lista2[i][2]:
        dif.append(i)

print(dif)
```

Otra forma de hacer esto es usar [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para recorrer ambas listas de forma paralela junto a [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para obtener el índice:

```
dif = []
for idx, (subl1, subl2) in enumerate(zip(lista1, lista2)):
    if subl1[2] != subl2[2]:
        dif.append(idx)

print(dif)
```

`dif` es una lista con los índices que difieren. Se asume que ambas listas tienen las mismas dimensiones.

Se puede rizar el rizo un poco más y usar listas por compresión:

```
lista1 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
lista2 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','10']]

dif = [idx for idx, (subl1, subl2) in enumerate(zip(lista1, lista2)) if subl1[2] != subl2[2]]

print(dif)
```

Además de las consideraciones (en parte subjetivas) sobre la legibilidad, la diferencia ente cada método es básicamente la eficiencia en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución, aunque esto es insignificante a no ser que tabajes con listas medianamente grandes, por ejemplo, para listas con 300000 elementos puedes encontrarte con:

- **Indizado mediante `for` + `range`:**

  58.3 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- **`for` + `zip` + `enumerate`:**

  46.7 ms ± 278 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
- **Lista por compresión con `zip` + `enumerate`:**

  42.5 ms ± 741 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando haces "for" sobre cualquier colección, obtienes el item, pero tu necesitas iterar sobre dos colecciones al mismo tiempo

Para eso puedes usar "enumerate", que además de entregarte el item, te entrega también un índice.

```
lista1 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','9']]
lista2 = [['1','2','3'],['4','5','6'],['7','8','10']]

for i, value in enumerate(lista1):
    print(i)
    print( value )
    print( lista2[i])
```

Aunque no es la solución, con el código anterior ya tienes todos los elementos necesarios para llegar a ella.